# Best way to make object globally accessible and manipulable in complex AngularJS app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop, object, global-variables

First of all, apologies if this question is a duplicate (I know that it appears suspiciously like one), but I have some specific requirements and I'm not sure that they are satisfied by other solutions. They might be, but I'm not at all certain.

I'm building a HTML5+CSS3+JS web-app using AngularJS to be deployed as a desktop application using node webkit. The app will enable the running of a competitive event, sorting teams and competitors by points as a tournament progresses, as well as several other tasks.

The app will have multiple components that all need to be able to access and edit the tournament, as well as locally store the tournament (probably as a JSON object).

Currently I'm planning on creating the tournament as a single object, with other objects (teams, competitors, judges) nested inside it. What is the best way to create this tournament in a way that satisfies my requirements?

I'll also need to be able to add new parts to the app later on and easily give those components the same ability (to view and update the tournament object).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Setup a factory/service and return the tournament object from there, or methods to work with it. You may then inject the service in whichever controller you want to have access to it. You may also define scope variables that reference the tournament object to make it accessible from your app's directives.

Answer (score 0):

I used to move all the global variable to $ootScope. But better dont clog it, you could use a single object for the purpose.

```
angular.module('sampleApp', [])
    .config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
        $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
    }])
    .run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.globalVars = {};
    }])
.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {

    $rootScope.globalVars.name = "Batman";
}])
 .directive('plugin', ['$compile,$rootScope', function ($compile, $rootScope) {
     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         link: function (scope, $element, attrs) {
             console.log($rootScope.globalVars.name); //Batman
         }
     }
 }]);
```